# Difference between "due to" and "thanks to"

Tags: idioms, differences

When should "due to" be preferred over "thanks to", and vice versa? When can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: would be interesting to throw "owing to" into the mix

Comment: @bagheera: [What is the difference between “owing to” and “due to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10325/)

Comment: @ottodidakt, and "because of"...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Thanks to* has a positive connotation (unless used sarcastically). *Due to* is more neutral - it can have both a negative and a positive connotation.

> We postponed our vacation plans due to the oil spill.
>
> It was due to Dwight's efforts that this question was asked.
>
> It was thanks to Dwight's efforts that this question was asked.

Answer (score 13):

> Due to: **as a result of**
>
> Thanks to: **with the help of**

Comment: The other meaning of _thanks to_ is _due to_. Both _due to_, and _thanks to_ can be used with the same meaning, but they have a different connotation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that *thanks to* is always used if the reason (i.e., the text after the *thanks to*) is of a positive nature and the result is positive too, whereas with *due to* the reason is typically of a negative nature and the result as well. Mismatches indicate a deeper meaning, usually with some irony:

- Thanks to the beautiful weather we had a splendid day. (*OK*)
- Thanks to the awful weather we were completely exhausted. (*Not OK*)
- Due to my car accident I was late at the meeting. (*OK*)
- Due to winning the contract John was promoted. (*Not OK*)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning difference has already been covered, but I think it’s worth pointing out that there is also a syntactical difference — the words *due* and *thanks* are not interchangeable, even in contexts where to do so would not affect the meaning.

Consider that, to replace *due* with *thanks*, this:

> We postponed our vacation plans due to the oil spill.

would usually be rephrased as this:

> Our vacation was postponed thanks to the oil spill.

Although in the second case, *due* could be substituted. This is because *due* can also be interpreted as *because*, which can be taken as a motivator for personal action, while *thanks* cannot. It does not make sense to say that *I did X thanks to Y*, although it would if you were to say *X was done thanks to Y*. Unless you are using a verb that implies an ability to act, rather than an action itself.

Having said all that, this is such an incredibly subtle distinction that I would not be surprised to discover that it varies by country, or even more finely, but to the best of my knowledge this is how they are — or should be — used.