# Does "due to" tend to have negative connotation?

Tags: connotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “due to” and “thanks to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/768/difference-between-due-to-and-thanks-to)

Looks like "due to" usually has negative connotation - *a plane crashed due to fog*, *unemployment increases due to automation*, etc.

Suppose I want to say "Thanks to this very cool technology everyone wins" - can I use "due to" in place of "thanks to" or does "due to" always mean some negative attribution?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not a duplicate.  This is a much more specific question.  The "duplicate" is about general interchangeability, while this is specifically about connotation.  It just so happens that the answer to the general question contains an answer to this one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think "due to" has any negative connotations. It can be used positively or negatively.

In your sentence, "Due to..." would be as appropriate as "Thanks to..."